# How to find Center Point from geometry arcgis android?

Tags: android, computational-geometry, arcgis

I am developing one application in that i want to show call out in center of geometry on my map I am new to arcgis.I tried so much but i am unable to get call out in center,please anybody help me how to solve this problem

my code

```
SimpleFillSymbol sfs = new SimpleFillSymbol(
                                        Color.RED);
                                sfs.setAlpha(5);
                                graphic = new Graphic(feature.getGeometry(),
                                        sfs, feature.getAttributes());
                                Polygon polygon = (Polygon) graphic
                                        .getGeometry();




                                int polygonpointscount=polygon.getPointCount();
                                if(polygonpointscount!=0)
                                {
                                    pointsize=polygonpointscount/2;
                                }
                                Point midpoint = polygon.getPoint(pointsize);
                                Callout callout = mMapView.getCallout();  
                                if (callout != null
                                        && callout.isShowing()) {
                                    callout.hide();
                                }
                                //Set the content, show the view  
                                callout.setContent(adminsearchloadView(governorate_Name,                              
                                area_Name,
                                        block_Number)); 
                                callout.setStyle(R.xml.calloutstyle);  
                                callout.setMaxHeight(100000);
                                callout.setMaxWidth(100000);
                                callout.refresh();
                                callout.show(midpoint);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **use [`GeometryEngine.getLabelPointForPolygon(Polygon, SpatialReference)`](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/geometry/GeometryEngine.html)**.

Long answer:

From your code...

```
int polygonpointscount=polygon.getPointCount();
if(polygonpointscount!=0)
{
    pointsize=polygonpointscount/2;
}
```

`Polygon.getPointCount()` returns the vertices of the polygon. For example, if the polygon is a rectangle, `getPointCount()` returns the corners. So your `Callout` will be at one of the corners instead of at the centroid.

Instead, **use [`GeometryEngine.getLabelPointForPolygon(Polygon, SpatialReference)`](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/geometry/GeometryEngine.html)** . It doesn't guarantee to return the centroid, but it returns an interior point that is good for labeling (and it looks like the centroid to me). Make sure you pass a `SpatialReference` object that tells `getLabelPointForPolygon` what the spatial reference of your polygon is.

If you must have the centroid, you'll need to create a geoprocessing service based on ArcGIS's [Feature to Point](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/feature-to-point.htm) tool. However, `getLabelPointForPolygon` is much easier to implement and faster to execute and probably satisfies your need.

Comment: Thank you very much @Gary,solved my problem,i have another problem with polyline,i am unable to get center point of polyline,please tell me how to get center point of polyline and extent

Comment: You could try [MultiPath.queryEnvelope(Envelope)](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/geometry/MultiPath.html) (Polyline extends MultiPath) to get the bounding box for your polyline and then call Envelope's getCenter, getCenterX, and getCenterY methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you use arcgis server you can try "feature to point": http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003m000000 to calculate centroid layer.

Comment: i am using arcgis server but could not understand ur example

Comment: You may save all of the geometries to gdb. Open the gdb in arccatalog, and calculate it's centroid using feature to point tool. Then you may publish the new centroid layer on your arcgis server as a new layer